# lucene API textSimilarity

Tags: java, lucene, nlp, information-retrieval

i am writing a project on plagiarism detection with Java, 
in this case for the first step i need to do the following tasks :

```
inputing  file (txt, .pdf, .doc)
convert the file content to text
removing stop words
tokenizng into n-gram
processing the text-similarity algorithms on the texts
reporting plagiarism detection signs
```

i did these steps by coding myself, but now i feel a lot of performance lacks in it, so i started using available API es for my work, such as word vector tool(http://sourceforge.net/projects/wvtool/) , wordnet and `Lucene`. the vvtool failed because of poor Doc available.
now my problem is how to do these with Lucene, should i input the file as a string and add it as a Field in a Document object or it has especial class for text similarity examin?
please help me on `Lucene` Library.
thanks in advance.

Ps- do you have any sample code source worked on Lucene i can start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that I am using for similarity library is as follows :

```
final SentenceSimilarityAssessor s=new SentenceSimilarityAssessor();
s.getSearchEngineHungarianSentenceSimilarity(s1, s2, SimilarityConstants.GOOGLE, SimilarityConstants.NGD_MEASURE, SimilarityConstants.TURNEY_SCORE_1);
```

You can try this.

Comment: there will be a Error, it seems that senteceSimilarityAssesor searches for a file in this path :
C:\work\montytagger-1.2\python\JMontyTagger.py
but there is no JmontyTagger.py file i can place it there!!
i think my package is not complete or miss somthing, also there is no Docs in the folder.

Comment: are you sure you have extracted the jar file sim_library.jar and added it to the build path of your project? because jmontyTagger and all other files are present inside the jar. What are you doing?

Comment: one advice : unzip the folder you have got from them. Create an eclipse project from this unzipped sources. You will then see 3 demo classes in src folder. Then you can compile and make a jar file out of it and use it for your purpose.

Comment: the zip folder i have is this:` SIMILARITYLIBRARY_RELEASE` 
and it has the following folders :[ AdjectiveInbox-adverbIndex-bin-lib-NounIndex-senseIndex-similarity-lib-src-stopw‌​ords-verbIndex ]
in the lib folder there is some .jar files, i added all of them to the project the sim_lib.jar is also there which is added, 
there is some jar files in the simlibrary_lib Folder, which i added them too. 
i Extracted sim_lib.jar and it hase those Folders and classes ive mentioned: assesors-searchengin-similarity

Comment: there is no compile errors!  all the classes are resolved and ok, 
the error i said is in Run time.

Comment: when i Run WordSearchEngineAssessorTest.java will be Errors:
com.yahoo.search.SearchException: Error calling service...
Underlying cause: com.yahoo.rest.RestException: Request failed, HTTP 404: Not Found...

Comment: NO !! DO as I said !! why aren't you understanding !!
I know which folders you have and everything. unzip SIMILARITYLIBRARY_RELEASE folder. Go to ecplise create a java project from existing sources, and specify path of the unzipped folder. Add src directory inside "SIMILARITYLIBRARY_RELEASE" as the source files' directory to this folder. You will get a full fledge project running !!

Comment: this src directory contains 3 classes which are demo classes for describing the functionality !!!

Comment: sorry for make you tire, thanks alot, but see these are exactly the steps i did, are those 3 class these? SentenceAssessorTest.java, WordSearchEngineAssessorTest.java and WordWordNetAssessorTest.java? 
they all run ok except WordSearchEngineAssessorTest.java with that Error i told you. 
your piece of code is what SentenceAssessorTest.java says. isnt it? 
it Runs and ok.

Comment: it has this out put, shows 0.89 similarity? but there is an Exception after it:

`Fast Lexicon Found! Now Loading!
Lexicon OK!
LexicalRuleParser OK!
ContextualRuleParser OK!
Fast Lexicon Found! Now Loading!
Lexicon OK!
LexicalRuleParser OK!
ContextualRuleParser OK!
0.8912392652192793
org.json.JSON**Exception**: JSONObject["responseData"] is not a JSONObject.
 at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:520)`

Comment: actually i get 0.8912392652192793 after several Runs, it usually print only exceptions after  ContextualRuleParser OK!

Comment: how it scale the similarity rate? i mean for example if it says Tet VERB similarity is 0.6515763931485331, 
which range i should report as plagiarism ?

Comment: 0.65 is same as 65% similarity. I don't know your criteria for deciding plagiarism. And yes it throws a lot of exceptions, you can find a way to compress those excepions and just get 0.89 as the output.

Comment: what is this library criteria for similarity? what is the relation with google ?

Comment: Their work has been explained in their paper : http://simlibrary.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/iswc2010.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about lucene, but for text similarity you can use ws4j library or [similarity library](http://simlibrary.wordpress.com/).

Comment: thanks, i downloaded the jar file but where can i find some good examples and docs about ws4j ?

Comment: Even I didn't find much good examples except for its own demo files
http://code.google.com/p/ws4j/source/browse/trunk/edu.cmu.lti.ws4j/src/main/java/edu/cmu/lti/ws4j/demo/SimilarityCalculationDemo.java?r=3
http://code.google.com/p/ws4j/

Comment: what about the similarity library you've mentioned? 
would you please give me a link?
you mean wordnet library ?

Comment: Yes. Even I faced the same problem. There is no or very less help. Please check my original answer I have pasted similarity library link

Comment: is it a open source library? because ive tried to obtain it before, by sending email to the address here (http://simlibrary.wordpress.com/obtaining-the-similarity-library/) but there was not any reply.

Comment: I got a reply from the guy in 2-3 days. Try sending him an email again.

Comment: No it is not open source, so you will have to obtain it from them. sorry

Comment: hmm, he replied and attached the library. where can i find how to use it?it seems no Docs available. just 3 classes trying to show how to use both WordNet and Search Engines in computing similarity between words or sentence, that just `WordWordNetAssessorTest.java` compiled without error.

Comment: Run `WordSearchEngineAssessorTest.java` results in Error: 
Testing NGD with Google 1.0595454168164353
com.yahoo.search.SearchException: Error calling service
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error xmlns="urn:yahoo:api">
  The following errors were detected:
  <Message>The service has been shut down.

Comment: would you please tell me the main classes of this library i can use in the case? like `WordNetAssessor`?

Comment: @parisa : I just used whatever that was written in the demo files and it worked fine. Are you sure you are not doing some error in build path or somewhwere similar?

Comment: the file i have is this: `SIMILARITYLIBRARY_RELEASE` and it has the following folders : AdjectiveInbox-adverbIndex-bin-lib-NounIndex-senseIndex-similarity-lib-src-stopwords-verbIndex
is it what you have?
where is demos ?